# Give anonymous access to explicit page in document library

Tags: document-library, permissions, publishing-page, anonymous-authentication

I have the following situation (SharePoint 2010):

A document library contains publishing pages. Anonymous access is enabled. The publishing pages are separeted in folders.

Now i have the situation that one of this folders (the pages inside the folder) should NOT be accessible by anonymous users. That's simple, I just had to break the inheritance of this folder any the anonymous access was gone. **Unfortunately ONE page inside this folder should be accessible by anonymous users.** How can I achieve this?

To my knowledge its not possible to achieve this by setting the rights programmatically. Its also not possible to set "NT AUTORITY/Anonymous logon" as user to a page.

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2010? If so you can break the inheritance of a single document.

Comment: Yes its SharePoint 2010. Breaking the inheritance let me protect single documents, but i dont have a possibility to assign anonymous access to single documents this way.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not support giving anonymous users access to items with broken permission inheritance. The last level you can do that is at the List level I think.

You need to move this one item to a new library or list.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot move the page out of that specific folder, you should be able to reinherit permissions on the folder and then break the permissions individually on the other documents that need to be secured.

I personally don't like to do granular permissions at an item level because it's so hard to tell what's secured and what's not. Ultimately, I would suggest moving things that should be secured into a sub site and then lock down that whole sub site so you know that anything in it is secure.